# Why do we need to chop/chunk the data while transmitting it over the network?

Tags: networking, data-transfer, packet

In networking, if the application can generate a stream of data then why can't the data be transmitted over the network as a stream of data? Instead, why is it chopped/chunked before sending across the network?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think segmented is the correct word for what you describe - rather packetized might be more appropriate.

There are lots of reasons to break data into packets, including -

- If there is an error only a small chunk of data needs to be resent.
- If multiple devices share a connection (which is almost always the case -especially as small networks aggregate to bigger ones, breaking data into packets allows multiple connections to work more-or-less simultaneously.
- Relatedly it allows multiple applications to share a single connection.
- Relatedly - for example in the case of VOIP or interactive traffic, using packets makes it possible to have 2 people communicating with each other at the same time (think full duplex rather then half duplex)
- If an intermediate connection goes down, or is overful and is shared with another connection, data needs to be broken up to take advantage of those links.
- At a hardware level, data sent in chunks is easier and more efficient.

Segmenting is different - it groups computers together, and allows you to concentrate access/control access between different groups of computers, and allows for routing flexibility.

Comment: Good answer - I'd put more emphasis on "sharing" a link - [packet switched](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_switching) vs [circuit switched](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_switching). Additionally, as you touched on the "_hardware level_", it might be worth mentioning buffering / MTUs / where is the data placed once received / etc...

Comment: You mentioned - "At a hardware level, data sent in chunks is easier and more efficient". Would be able to provide more detail on this? How it is more efficient to send data as chunks? I just got curious to understand this.

Comment: I'm not a hardware expert, but in the most general sense - computing can be looked at as ways of performing calculations/moving blocks of memory. By allowing the CPU to push a block of -say - 1500 bytes - to the network card and offloading the transmitting of it in 1 operation it needs to fo 1500 times less work then if it had to continuously send/stream 1 byte at a time, while monitoring to see if it was ok to send the next one. As soon as you are sending more then 1 byte (1 bit actually) you are packetising data - it's just a question of how large the packets are.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps it is best to compare packet switching with the method that it replaced: circuit switching.  Circuit switching is what telephones use.  When you want to place a call, you have to pick up the phone and dial someone, wait for them to answer, then, until you hang up, you have a dedicated connection to that person over which you can send as much or little data as you want.  You can't communicate with anyone else until you hang up on that circuit, then establish a new one, and if you aren't sending much data, you are wasting a lot of the capacity of the circuit.

Packet switching allows you to exchange data with anyone, anywhere, without bothering with setting up and tearing down circuits.  No wasted capacity to open lines that are underused, and you can carry on multiple conversations at once.